# request.POST.get() showing a None when print is used

Tags: django, django-views

Like the question said, when I print, it shows the list/string first then a "None" in the end just like this:

```
["a","b","c"]
"test"
None
None
```

*script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#export").click(function () {
              var test = "test";
              var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
              $.ajax({
                url: '/export/csv',
                data: {'array1': JSON.stringify(array1), 'test': JSON.stringify(test)},
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                }
              });
            });
        });
```

*views.py*

```
@csrf_exempt
def export_csv(request):

    print(request.method)
    test1 = request.POST.get('test')
    array1 = request.POST.get('array1')

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product-inventory.csv"'

    print(array1)
    print(test1)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Test1')

    for t in array1:
        writer.writerow([t])

    return response
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^export/csv$', product_views.export_csv, name='export_csv')
```

I know I'm missing something in my *views.py*. If you could point me to the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No sir I'm not. That's the only 2 prints in my app.

Comment: Sorry sir. I got it wrong. I edited my question to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: It could be that when the values are printed that's `POST` request while `None` values are getting printed in `GET` request of the same URL.

Comment: so I'm print two instances of `array1` and `test1`, sir?

Comment: Could you also try printing `request.method` in the starting of the view and see what all output do you get?

Comment: Please include the entire view

Comment: This is the result of the request.method sir. `POST
["a","b","c"]
GET
"test"
None
None`

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier in the comment this URL is being fetched from somewhere else using `GET` request too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Copied from my comments:*

> It could be that when the values are printed that's POST request while None values are getting printed in GET request of the same URL.

Looking at the output of `print(request.method)` it is confirmed that the URL is being accessed two times. One with `POST` method and other time with `GET` method.

`None` values are printed during the `GET` method request because at that time `request.POST` doesn't contain the keys you are looking for.

If you only want to serve `POST` methods, you could [restrict the allowed HTTP methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods)

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def export_csv(request):
    .... # your implementation
```

But, you should also try to find out the origin of the `GET` method first.

Comment: I'll try this out now sir. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried this but I'm getting "Method not Allowed" thus I can't go to the next view. I tried separating my template to separate my POST and GET but still does not work.

Comment: Never mind my last questions sir. I just used `request.session`. Thanks for the time and help.